# How to assert in laravel 5.4 that each record in the list has at least enlisted attributes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.4

I am just moving app from laravel 5.3 to 5.4.
In laravel 5.3 in my API tests I could verify that each record in response has given attributes with following code:

```
$this->json('get', '/api/course-types')
        ->seeJsonStructure([
            '*' => ['id', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']
        ]);
```

How I can do the same with laravel 5.4?

There is no such method in [Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.html)

Comment: Yes, it's gone. You can use `assertJson` or you can replicate the [code for `seeJsonStructure`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php#L341-L374). To be clear, it was never in `TestResponse`, but rather in `MakesHttpRequests` trait.

Answer (score 1):

I *believe* you are looking for `assertJson()` or `assertExactJson()`.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/http-tests#testing-json-apis):

> The assertJson method converts the given array into JSON, and then verifies that the JSON fragment occurs anywhere within the entire JSON response returned by the application. So, if there are other properties in the JSON response, this test will still pass as long as the given fragment is present.

And relevant code:

```
$response = $this->json('POST', '/user', ['name' => 'Sally']);

$response
    ->assertStatus(200)
    ->assertJson([
        'created' => true,
    ]);
```

`assertExactJson()` will look for an exact match, whereas `assertJson()` simply verifies the existance of your parameters in the response. Hope it helps!

Comment: I want to check resposne structure not content. This dind't work.

Answer (score 1):

The browserkit testing functionality was replaced with Laravel Dusk. The original functionality has been moved to its own package: [laravel/browser-kit-testing](https://github.com/laravel/browser-kit-testing).

> This package provides a backwards compatibility layer for Laravel 5.3 style "BrowserKit" testing on Laravel 5.4.

You will need to follow the installation and usage instructions on that package, and then your existing tests will work as they did in 5.3.

Comment: Didn't work. The same test failed with 2 errors now:  1) `PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Argument #1 (No Value) of PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertJson() must be a string` 
2) `Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Feature\ExampleTest::assertStatus()`

Comment: @gandra404 It sounds like you're mixing the two test suites. A test class can use only either the new testing functionality (Laravel Dusk) or the old testing functionality (BrowserKit). `seeJsonStructure()` is only available in the BrowserKit test suite. `assertStatus()` is only available in the Dusk test suite.

Comment: this is very weird. I am writing tests for API backend app. There is no visual interfaces, only REST endpoints and the basic thing which I expect from one endpoint is: 
- to see json response
- to check http status code
- to check that json respons has certain structure 

and now I have to split ths in 2 different tests?
If this is true than I ma having new problem.

Comment: @gandra404 Basically, if you're attempting to use old BrowserKit suite, look at the [testing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/application-testing) for Laravel 5.3. If you're attempting to use the new Dusk suite, look at the [testing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/http-tests) for Laravel 5.4. For example, if using Dusk, you would use the new `assertStatus()` method, but if using BrowserKit, you would use the old `assertResponseStatus()` method.

Comment: I do not have any preference to use Dusk or BrowserKit. I am only as how to make make test which works on laravel 5.3 to pass on laravel 5.4 and not to split the in different classes?

Answer (score 0):

I use `seeJsonStructure()` a lot, too, so I hacked together a little substitute to place in my own `TestCase`. Hopefully it's helpful to someone, or someone can advice me on a better solution:

Added to my `TestCase`:

```
public function seeJsonStructure(TestResponse $response = null, array $structure = null, $responseData = null)
{
    if ($response && !$responseData) {
        $responseData = $response->decodeResponseJson();
    }
    if (is_null($structure)) {
        return $response->assertJson($responseData);
    }
    foreach ($structure as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) && $key === '*') {
            $this->assertInternalType('array', $responseData);
            foreach ($responseData as $responseDataItem) {
                $this->seeJsonStructure(null, $structure['*'], $responseDataItem);
            }
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $responseData);
            $this->seeJsonStructure(null, $structure[$key], $responseData[$key]);
        } else {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey($value, $responseData);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Then, I had to update my tests, so I pass the response as the first argument when calling this method. Example for `SomeTest`:

```
$response = $this->json('POST', $url, [
    'id' => $user->id
]);

$this->seeJsonStructure($response, [
    'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'
]);
```

The original Laravel method was: https://github.com/laravel/browser-kit-testing/blob/85f9a14a63bf5a287740002fcbc4352587f8a113/src/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php#L348